# LUIS Out of call volume quota. Quota will be replenished

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I started receiving this message from when querying LUIS using the starter key, however, I reached only 600 hits to the end point so far as per the dashboard across all apps (the limit is 1000 right?).

I added a new key using an azure subscription, but the docs say that when developing or authoring, I should be using the authoring key. My questions are:

1- How am I getting this error when I just reached 700 hits only across all my LUIS apps.

2- if I want to use the new endpoint key, do I do development/testing using this key since I can't use the authoring one for now? What's the best practice in this case?

Answer (score 2):

### Reaching the quota:

The quota is about several things:

- global usage
- per second/minute usage

You probably have reached the quota per second? Moreover, the value of number of hits on the portal may not be working, I already had a LUIS projects showing 0 hits for weeks whereas it was used.

You will found below the values:

[image: quotas]

Link: Microsoft documentation about limits [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-boundaries?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365#key-limits)

### Using new key

You should use an **endpoint key** when you just query LUIS. From the documentation:

> LUIS uses two keys: authoring and endpoint. The authoring key is
> created for you automatically when you create your LUIS account. When
> you are ready to publish your LUIS app, you need to create the
> endpoint key, assign it to your LUIS app, and use it with the endpoint
> query.

Comment: Thanks @Nicolas .. yes I know I should use the endpoint key when querying LUIS, but my question is that MS says use the authoring key when testing, developing, etc.. so now I need to develop and test and my authoring key isn't working. What to do in this case? I have 2 keys generated from LUIS in Azure, do I use one as an endpoint key and the other as an authoring key?

Comment: The keys generated on Azure are endpoint keys (see above: it's invalid for authoring actions), you cannot "choose" what kind of key they will be. Your Authoring key is on your profile on LUIS portal (click on your name > profile), you can try to reset it. And for the authoring operations (made with this authoring key), the quota is 1 million / month (and 5 / second) so you should not be blocked on authoring actions.

Comment: In a few words: stop using your authoring key from your projects/applications: publish your LUIS app using your endpoint key created on Azure (on LUIS portal, PUBLISH menu, add your key in "Resources and Keys"). Your Authoring key will still be used for your actions on LUIS portal when you manage your project

Comment: Hi Nicolas, so when you say it's for authoring actions and it's 1 million/month. How come I reached the limit? I am the only one testing and developing, so I can't be making more than 5/second, not even 2 requests per second. I tried reseting the key when I go to my name > profile, but it's just updated there, if I go back to the LUIS app, the starter key still shows the old one.

Comment: "so I can't be making more than 5/second, not even 2 requests per second": maybe LUIS portal is using this key and making many calls to display the screens

Comment: OK. So if I reset the key, I can use it for another 1 million requests for authoring? When you say authoring, what does it mean exactly, does it mean just things I can do in LUIS portal, or they include testing in the emulator as well?

Comment: Authoring actions = everything about management of your app: creating, adding/deteling intents/utterances etc. Endpoint actions = query your app to get the results, that's all. For the reset, honestly, I don't know